# OO Class Design for ATM card

Tags: java, encapsulation, solid-principles

I have to design a Class for ATM cards with the following attributes:

1. Cardholder Name
2. Card Number
3. Pin

Other than getters and setters, I have a method to validate the pin of the ATM. As per the principle of encapsulation all the methods related to the ATM should be part of the ATM class.

But in case, later we need to change the business logic of the validate method. We shouldn't modify the class as per the Open-Closed principle and extending the class and creating a new class will make me change the instantiation of the ATM class from the complete project.

One way is to have a factory pattern which gives me the ATM object and later when I extend the class I will change the ATM object to the NewATM object.

Now I have the following questions for the problem:

1. Should the validate method be part of the ATM class?
2. Is there any other way of solving the problem?

Comment: Post what you have attempted so far. It's not hard to write a POJO.

Comment: To answer question #1, write an abstract `CardValidator` class with a validate (`boolean`) method. Then create a child class called `AtmCardValidator` and define how to validate an ATM card.

Comment: I would assume, following SRP that your class should only be responsible for one thing and if Validation is in addition to what it does, separate validation into a validator class you inject.

Comment: The `Card` class should have `name` and `number` properties. An `AtmCard` should extend the `Card` and provide an additional `pin` property.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl if there will only be ATMCards at this time it might not even be needed to already decide what to add into a "base" class and what into an "extending" class. YAGNI? Write, bare minimum abstraction, write your unit test, refactor as requirements come to light? (I'm just asking)

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the quick help. Validate method should be in the ATM class which will call the validate pin method of the injected validator class?

Comment: Taking what @Mr.Polywhirl said into consideration a ATMCardValidator might be a good choice as it will only be responsible for validation. You might even get a PinValidator you inject into the ATMCardValidator etc.. That way the ATMCard validator just calls a set of `.Validate` on a possible collection of validators? Anyway, only brainstorming here.

Comment: @Fran One more doubt here, is it ok to have a injected class in a normal POJO?

Comment: @Karan If it's only used to hold data and no logic on it's own than I assume you need another class that orchestrates the Validation i.e: Operation, Manager, etc.. using your POJO as a property that you can write unit tests against.

Comment: @Fran but shouldn't everything related to the ATM be the part of the ATM class as per the encapsulation principle?

Comment: @Karan It is up to you which principle you want to follow, but you can't follow them all as some will clash with each other. The main thing is to make a choice and stick with it to ensure you are applying the same across the whole application. Personally (on a very general level) I let my unit tests drive a lot of those decisions.  If I can't mock/stub something or a method has side effects causing false negative/positive results or fail my tests for unrelated reasons I rethink my approach.

Comment: @Karan Also, if your application is rather small, sure, throw it all into a single class, no need to overkill on abstraction if not needed. Then as the application grows, abstract as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Karan,
I don't really know Java but this is how I would do it using SOLID:

```
interface IAtmCard 
{
    string CardholderName { get; set; }
    string CardNumber { get; set; }
}

interface IPin
{
    string Pin { get; set; }
}

class AtmCard : IPin, IAtmCard
{
    // Implement IAtmCard
    public string CardholderName { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    // Implement IPin
    public string Pin { get; set; }
}

static class ATM
{
    // This way the ValidatePin function only depends on the IPin interface
    public static bool ValidatePin(IPin card, string providedPin)
    {
        return card.Pin == providedPin;
    }
}
```

I think the actual ATM Card is a completely separate object from the ATM logic itself.  The ATM Card should not be responsible for both storing it's information and validating itself.